# Least Squares Derivation—Simple Algebraic Simplification

Tags: calculus, statistics

Mathematics StackExchange!

I'm reading the following derivation of least squares, and I'm trying to figure out how the author went from the last step at the bottom of pg. 7 to the final equation (11) at the top of pg. 8.

[Harvard.edu](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/OLSDerivation.pdf)

More specifically, why is the denominator a difference of two terms? Aren't the terms in the denominator summed in the prior step?

I would expect the answer to be
$$
b_1=\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{\textrm{i=1}}^{n}y_ix_{i}-\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\sum_{\textrm{i=1}}^{n}y_i\sum_{\textrm{i=1}}^{n}x_{i}\right)}{\displaystyle\sum_{\textrm{i=1}}^{n}x_{i}^2+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\sum_{\textrm{i=1}}^{n}x_{i}\right)^{2}}
$$

I'm no statistician, but the algebra here just doesn't seem correct.

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken, but a snapshot is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170224003836/http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/OLSDerivation.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final formula given in (11) in the link is **correct**.

However, there is an error in the derivation: following "Multiplying out the last term on the right, we get:" (this is on page 7), the author should have had $+$ in front of $b_1$ on the RHS instead of $-$. This error came from incorrect removal of the square brackets from the preceding equation.

p.s. You should strive to make your post self-contained so, in particular, a link to an external document that may later be taken down isn't encouraged.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Kim! As for self-contained posts, rather than retyping the entire (or subsequently large portions of) the derivation, are photos okay to include in a post (i.e., screen captures)?

Comment: Legible photos can be acceptable. Just browse around and have a look a the Help Center, you'll be able to a rough approximate of what is acceptable and what is not.